# Remove Chrome extension via code

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I have created a Chrome application. When the user adds it to the Chrome browser, a form is opened as a part of the installation. I want to delete the added extension when the installation is not done correctly.

How do I trigger deletion of a Chrome extension?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

An extension can remove itself by calling [`chrome.management.uninstallSelf();`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/management.html#method-uninstallSelf).

If your extension wants to remove another extension, [declare](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/declare_permissions.html) the `management` permission in the manifest file and call [`chrome.management.uninstall('<id of other extension>');`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/management.html#method-uninstall).

You cannot uninstall an extension from the command line any more as of Chrome 36.0.1960.0 (using `--uninstall-extension`, [crbug 351294](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=351294)).

Comment: *Comment from [user3860673](http://stackoverflow.com/users/3860673/user3860673):* As of Chrome 36 the --uninstall-extension command line doesn't work.

Comment: @ArtjomB.: thanks artjom....if you know the workaround then do post it as an answer. would be helpful for people referring this in future.

Comment: // , You _can_ manually delete the files of the offending extension if you want to neuter it, say, if it's click-jacking the browser, redirecting away from chrome://extensions, or otherwise preventing Chromium from managing its own extensions.

Comment: // , So basically this only works if your extension isn't, well, evil

Answer (score 6):

If anyone is looking for an alternative to `--uninstall-extension`, here is a try:
sadly this doesn't work from command line, but you can be used to programmatically do stuff with extensions.

## manifest.json

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "Uninstaller",
  "version": "1.0",
  "description": "Uninstalls hardcoded extensions.",
  "permissions": [ "management" ],
  "browser_action": { },
  "background": { "scripts": ["background.js"] }
}
```

## background.js

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
  chrome.management.uninstall('ckibcdccnfeookdmbahgiakhnjcddpki');
  chrome.management.uninstallSelf();
});
```

## Usage

1. Save the above two files to a new folder
2. Change the ID of the extension you want to uninstall in `background.js`
3. Open chrome://extensions (or *Menu > Settings > Extensions*)
4. Tick *Developer mode*
5. Click *Load unpacked extension*
6. Browse the folder you saved the files to
7. Click the new icon that appears next to the hamburger menu
   in the top right corner (puzzle piece)
8. Untick *Developer mode*
9. Delete the folder with the two files

Comment: How does this site do both install/uninstall from their site. I don't think they are hosting a copy of it https://chromewebstore.google.com/detail/chatgpt-in-whatsapp/jncmcndmaelageckhnlapojheokockch

Comment: Very good question. I was always under the impression that `chromewebstore.google.com` is special (i.e. might have hardcoded logic in Chrome itself to allow doing more).

Comment: I see, So are both chromewebstore.google.com and chrome.google.com/webstore same ? why don't google showcase chromewebstore.google.com in their search results then?

Comment: moreover when I check the requests made by chromewebstore.google.com and chrome.google.com/webstore for clicking install, they aren't same either.

Answer (score 2):

Let's say you really, really need to do this from the command line, and only the command line, or from another system far far away entirely. Somehow that situation keeps coming up for people... can't imagine why.

In my case, I came across an extension that actually prevented me from opening `chrome://extensions`. O.O

This meant that I could not use most of the other answers on this page without some serious forethought.

Anyway, if you're one of those unlucky folks somehow limited to good old bash, zsh, ncurses, whatever, something like the following might help as a starting point:

```
I just used the following method to ditch an evil extension in Chromium Version 51.0.2704.79 on an Ubuntu 14.04 (64-bit) system: 
% sudo add-apt-repository ppa:pgolm/the-silver-searcher
% sudo apt-get update
% sudo apt-get install the-silver-searcher  ## Add a searcher tool
% cd ~/.config/chromium/Default/Extensions  ## Go to the default folder for Chromium Extensions.
% ls -rolath  ## List the contents in order of most recently modified.
total 16K
drwx------  3 fu 4.0K Sep  4 20:45 gcbombkclmclpchdgiimedpiimgmedia
drwx------  3 fu 4.0K Sep  4 20:45 bilkyoucmkafdfolokijcfjliaokphfk
drwx------  3 fu 4.0K Sep  5 13:56 leniggcoacklhapakkkcpdbppfkghcmi
drwx------  3 fu 4.0K Sep  5 14:37 fvuckkukegcagdloljackdonpwnmedph
%  ## Looks like we have two suspicious candidates, here, to possibly delete. 
% aptitude search silversearcher ; aptitude install silversearcher-ag ## - very fast grep-like program, altenative to ack-grep
% ag --literal "adclick" ; ag --literal "_trackPageview" ; ag --literal "hijack" ## Etc. I did a bunch of 
     ## separate little searches 
     ## until I found the item that 
     ## looked like it was installed 
     ## most recently and had the 
     ## most suspicious keywords. 
% ag --literal '"version": "' | grep leniggcoacklhapakkkcpdbppfkghcmi  
    ## The above line finds the versions 
    ## of the extension to which I took offense.
% rm -rf leniggcoacklhapakkkcpdbppfkghcmi  
    ## Remove the files for the extension 
    ## to which I took offense.
```

I then started Chromium, happily went along to my chrome://extensions link, looked at the version information for the few most recently installed extensions, compared them to the output I found from `ag --literal '"version": "' | grep leniggcoacklhapakkkcpdbppfkghcmi`, and clicked the little trash can button next to that extension.

[image: joy at last]

Hope that gives you some ideas. It worked for me. I found that out mostly by guesswork and searching on http://duckduckgo.com. Your results may vary, which is good!

Comment: To make life easier, on a Windows machine you can go to C:\Users\myusername\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Extensions and see all of your extensions currently installed. Easier if you understand Javascript so you can understand what the code is doing in each folder and interpret the malicious extension.

Comment: // , I did this from GNU/Linux. Might be worth copying my answer and turning it into one that's compatible with Winblows, for users of that OS. I mentioned a few keywords that tend to indicate annoying extensions. What heuristics can you recommend for looking for malicious extensions?

Comment: No idea in terms of heuristics unfortunately. It was more being able to tell what an extension is doing if you read through the JS files for each extension and be able to tell what's happening. If, for some reason, you have a ton of extensions and it's unreasonable to sift through each extension folder on disk, I don't know what to suggest :)